# Maintaining data positions when zooming in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3.js to plot a lot of little data points (as circles) on a map. No big deal there. I would like to add the ability to zoom and pan, however.

I have been using this version of the zooming function: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340

It works great on my map base (e.g. the country forms). But it does not move the data points. (I attempted to simply add the data to the "features" layer but this did not work well — it put them underneath the landforms and made it so that they no longer triggered mouseover events, presumably because they are under the layer that looks for pan/zoom events.)

Here is what my map look like:

[image: My map]

If I do nothing when I pan/zoom, it obviously doesn't look very good:

[image: My map, zoomed]

I have tried to use the zoom/translate events to adjust the projection, then re-project the data points. This works great for panning but totally fails for zooming:

[image: My map, panned and zoomed]

You can't really tell from the image above but the relative distances between the images have indeed moved with the zooming. But the pan translation is totally off.

Here is the function I am using to handle the zooming:

```
function zoomed() {
features.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
features.select(".state-border").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
features.select(".county-border").style("stroke-width", .5 / d3.event.scale + "px");

projection.scale(projection_scale*d3.event.scale);
projection.translate([((width/2)+d3.event.translate[0]),((height/2)+d3.event.translate[1])]);

for(i in cdata) {
    var ll = cdata[i].LatLng.split(",");
    if(!ll[0]) ll[0]=-500;
    if(!ll[1]) ll[1]=-500;
    positions[cdata[i].id]=(projection([parseFloat(ll[1]),parseFloat(ll[0])]));
}
 svg.selectAll(".data_circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return positions[d.id][0]; })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return positions[d.id][1]; })
;
```

}

cdata is an object with all of my csv-loaded data in it, including lat/lng data as a comma-separated string (hence the split). The -500 thing is just for bad data; it puts it where you can't see it (a temporary fix). positions is an array of all the projected lat/lng positions.

Obviously I'm thinking about this incorrectly. I've tried scaling the translate function by the zoom amount (e.g. ((width/2)+d3.event.translate[0])*d3.event.scale) ) but this produces really odd results as well (it seems to help a bit but the pan/zoom become a little "unhinged" — it is almost as if the dots are hovering above the map in 3D space, and moving left and right makes them almost seem a little stereoscopic... anyway, not the effect I am trying to produce).

What should I be doing differently? Again, any solution needs to take into account that the dots have mouseover events on them that need to be able to fire.

I've searched the zooming D3 examples for something that does this and not found one, which surprised me, since this seemed like kind of basic functionality (and is something easy to do in Google Maps, for once), but maybe I didn't search deep enough or in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out! It suddenly occurred to me what the problem was. All it required was changing:

```
projection.translate([((width/2)+d3.event.translate[0]),((height/2)+d3.event.translate[1])]);
```

to

```
projection.translate([((width*d3.event.scale/2)+d3.event.translate[0]),((height*d3.event.scale/2)+d3.event.translate[1])]);
```

Which makes sense — the original width/height were not the same because it was being zoomed, so I needed to apply the translation to the zoomed width/height. Now it works great.